# Willst du etwas essen vs Willst du etwas zu Essen?

Tags: nominalization

My question is about the infinitive without zu. I have learned that modal verbs take the infinitve without zu. So how is it possible that "Willst du etwas zu essen" is correct? Is it maybe because of the word "etwas"? Because we don't say "Willst du zu essen", we say " Willst du essen?" Right

*Willst du etwas essen means* Do you want to eat something?
*Willst du etwas zu essen* means Do you want something to eat?
Willst du etwas zu Essen?
Willst du etwas zum Essen?

Answer (score 1):

tl,dr: It's an error.

[Zu](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zu) has many applications.

In this case it should be the form 'zu' + infinitive of a verb.

> Willst du etwas zu essen ?

would be correct.

The substantive 'das Essen' (the meal) could be used whith 'zu' where the preposition introduces an add-on to something:

> Willst du Ketchup zu deinem Essen ?

or more general

> Willst du etwas zu deinem Essen dazu ?

which could be abbreviated to a less clear and concise

> Willst du etwas zu dem/zum Essen ?

Comment: My question is actually about the infinitive without zu. I have learned that modal verbs take the infinitve without zu. So how is it possible that "Willst du etwas zu essen" is correct? Is it maybe because of the word "etwas"? Because we don't say "Willst du zu essen", we say " Willst du essen?" Right?